# How to change from Xterm to default terminal in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, xterm

I know it can be silly question but I suddenly clicked some shortcup/or somemething else occur - and my default ubuntu terminal changed to Xterm.
How to revert this? Or change xterm to "normal" terminal.
Im totally new in Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```